# Comments Display Error

Tags: comments

I have followed the EE 2.8.1 docs to create user comments to be displayed against the relevant channel entry on a singular page, as suggested.

However, the comments from the whole channel overall are being displayed and not just the relating entry itself.

Below is my code if anyone can help?

```
<div class="left-col-pages full-width">
  <h2>Job Applications</h2>
<hr>
  {exp:channel:entries channel="jobs" orderby="title" sort="asc|desc" limit="1"}
  <h3>{vacancy}</h3>
    {exp:member:custom_profile_data}
    {if photo}
    <img src="{photo_url}" alt="{author}" width="60" height="60" class="right"/>
    {if:else}
    <img src="{site_url}images/member_photos/image-member-placeholder.gif" alt="No Image" width="60" height="60" class="right"/>
    {/if}
  {/exp:member:custom_profile_data}
    <p>{vacancy} for {company}, {area}</p>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
<hr>
  {/exp:channel:entries}
   <!-- Show Applications -->
   {exp:comment:entries channel="jobs" orderby="name" sort="asc|desc" limit="2000" dynamic="no"}
   {if photo}
   <img src="{photo_url}" width="60" height="60" alt="{author}'s photo" />
   {if:else}
   <img src="{site_url}images/member_photos/image-member-placeholder.gif" alt="No Image" width="60" height="60"/>
   {/if}
   <p><small>{comment_date format="%d.%m.%Y"}, {name}</small></p>
   <p>{comment}</p>
   {/exp:comment:entries}           
  <hr>              
</div>
```

This is placed as an embed should that make any difference?

Thanks in advance
Scott

Comment: Why two `sort`s but just one `orderby`?

Answer (score 1):

It's the `dynamic` parameter.

If you set it to `no`, EECMS will not filter the comments to the entry on URL.

```
{exp:comment:entries channel="jobs" orderby="name" sort="asc" limit="2000"}
```